# How to hide the master popover view on first-time app load?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have nice helper functions that allow me to show/hide the master popover view controller. However, I can not for the life of me figure out how to hide it on initialization, so that it is hidden when the app first starts.

I've tried a couple of things (such as trying to dismiss is from the viewLoaded or viewDidAppear) but these throw strange errors (e.g. too made slider counts...etc).

Now I'm starting to believe there must be a simpler, and the right way, to do this.

Comment: Where are you presenting your `UIPopoverController`? If you could post the code that'd be great.

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea. When i created the project i just used the UISplitViewController template. The popover controller reference is defined in the details view controller, which is weird to me. However, the IB suggests it is more complex than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to hide the splitviewController Master Popover? Which orientation would make this question more specific. I will assume you are in fact trying to hide the SplitView MasterPopover in landscape (since it should already be hidden in portrait).

Do this:
Your `detailViewController` should have `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`. And simply just drop this code in:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    return YES;
}
```

This will make popoverView hidden when the app starts up. Let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: i'll give this a try. but I'm not sure if i should override this method. I believe it only applies to iOS 5.0+, and also, when i enable this method i believe 2 other init methods become obsolete (they don't get called anymore). Also, in landscape mode the popover always exist. Portrait is the mode that i'd like to see be hidden on start up.

Comment: Ok. I add this method and made it return YES. But still the popover still shows up initially (in portrait mode).

Comment: Apologies. I did not require the above mentioned suggestions. The problem was that I had a bug where I was forcing the popover to show when a block animation is completed (which the animation is invoked on start of the app).

Comment: Correct, as I mentioned before, "it should already be hidden in portrait" If it does not, you probably are the one doing it :) Cheers!